# Navigation drawer not showing

Tags: java, android, xml

So literally I copied everything from sample android app for navigation drawer, in sample app it shows, in my it does not.

I'll paste the code below, you tell me if you need any more files!

Here's the code

```
public class NavigacijskiIzbornik extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigacijski_izbornik);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new NavigacijaPrviFragment()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigacijski_izbornik, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_prviLayout) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new NavigacijaDrugiFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_drugiLayout) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_treciLayout) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Activity of drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_prviLayout" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_drugiLayout" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_treciLayout" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Activity navigacijski izbornik

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">



    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_navigacijski_izbornik"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigacijski_izbornik"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigacijski_izbornik_drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: **No Debugging please!**. What's the error. Paste your logcat!

Comment: There's no error! Drawer just doesn't show in app

Comment: Can you provide the xml for the activity view?

Comment: what specific activity?

Comment: xml for layout/activity_navigacijski_izbornik

Comment: you will be able to open it with swipe gesture and not using click on hamburger icon. Is it true?

Comment: No, it doesn't open with the swipe

Comment: Why to copy paste there is an option in android studio to create activity with navigation drawer . Check this out http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android

Comment: I mean, I created navigation drawer layout from android studio templates ofc, but it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

do like bellow..

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/rel_drawer_app"
                layout="@layout/home_drawer" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```